# Variable not defined within function

Tags: html, css, sass, codepen

I'm relatively new to programming. That being said, I was trying my hand at modifying a CSS animation on CodePen (without any prior knowledge of SASS and little with CSS), and I wanted to implement an animated gradient background with stars.

This was the original: https://codepen.io/saransh/pen/BKJun

```js
/*
Nothing to see here :)
Made by @screenshake
linkedin.com/in/saranshsinha
*/
```

```css
@import compass


// n is number of stars required
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) 
    $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
    @for $i from 2 through $n
        $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

    @return unquote($value)

    $shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700)
    $shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200)
    $shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100)

html
    height: 100%
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1B2735 0%, #090A0F 100%)
    overflow: hidden
    
#stars
    width: 1px
    height: 1px
    background: transparent
    box-shadow: $shadows-small
    animation   : animStar 50s linear infinite
    
    &:after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 1px
        height: 1px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-small
    
#stars2
    width: 2px
    height: 2px
    background: transparent
    box-shadow: $shadows-medium
    animation   : animStar 100s linear infinite
    
    &:after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 2px
        height: 2px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-medium
    
#stars3
    width: 3px
    height: 3px
    background: transparent
    box-shadow: $shadows-big
    animation   : animStar 150s linear infinite
    
    &:after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 3px
        height: 3px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-big

#title
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    left: 0
    right: 0
  
    color: #FFF
    text-align: center
    font-family: 'lato',sans-serif
    font-weight: 300
    font-size: 50px
    letter-spacing: 10px
  
    margin-top: -60px
    padding-left: 10px
  
    span
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #38495a)
        -webkit-background-clip: text
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
    
@keyframes animStar
    from 
        transform: translateY(0px)
    to  
        transform: translateY(-2000px)
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
#stars
#stars2
#stars3
#title
    %span
        PURE CSS
    %br
    %span
        PARALLAX PIXEL STARS
```

And this is my attempt: https://codepen.io/keironss/pen/qMErr

```js
/*
Authored by @screenshake and @keironss
*/
```

```css
@import compass


@function multiple-box-shadow ($n)
    $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
    @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

    @return unquote($value)
  
    $shadows-small: multiple-box-shadow(625)
    $shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(250)
    $shadows-big: multiple-box-shadow(125)
 

html
    height: 100%
    overflow: hidden
    background: linear-gradient(#B0AEC4, #616161)

#stars
    width: .5px
    height: .5px
    background: #C3C3C3
    box-shadow: $shadows-small
    animation: animStar 50s linear infinite
 

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: .5px
        height: .5px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-small

#stars2
    width: 1px
    height: 1px
    background: #7F7E84
    box-shadow: $shadows-medium
    animation: animStar 100s linear infinite

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 1px
        height: 1px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-medium

#stars3
    width: 2px
    height: 2px
    background: #626264
    box-shadow: $shadows-big
    animation: animStar 150s linear infinite

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 2px
        height: 2px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-big

@keyframes animStar
    from transform: translateY(0px)
    to transform: translateY(-2000px)

#r-stars
    width: .5px
    height: .5px
    background: #626264
    box-shadow: $shadows-small
    animation: r-animStar 50s linear infinite

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: .5px
        height: .5px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-small

#r-stars2
    width: 1px
    height: 1px
    background: #7F7E84
    box-shadow: $shadows-medium
    animation: r-animStar 100s linear infinite

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 1px
        height: 1px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-medium


#r-stars3
    width: 2px
    height: 2px
    background: #C3C3C3-
    box-shadow: $shadows-big
    animation: r-animStar 150s linear infinite

    &: after
        content: " "
        position: absolute
        top: 2000px
        width: 2px
        height: 2px
        background: transparent
        box-shadow: $shadows-big

@keyframes r-animStar
    from
        transform: translateY(-2000px)
    to
        transform: translateY(0px)
```

```html
#stars
#stars2
#stars3
#r-stars
#r-stars2
#r-stars3
```

I ran into a bunch of errors while developing this. The problems before were mostly indentation errors, but now the problem whenever I try to code the theme in CodePen is that `$shadows-small` is undefined in the `#stars` path and it seems to only pop up there.

Can anyone please give any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code that you have provided here, it looks like you are declaring `$shadows-small` inside the scope of your `multiple-box-shadow ($n)` function. Since it is scoped inside of this function, it is therefore inaccessible from the outside. Simply moving the variable declaration to a global context will resolve your issue. [(View the updated pen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOPLyV)

Your original:

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) 
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
  @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

  @return unquote($value)

  $shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700)
  $shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200)
  $shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100)
```

The corrected version:

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) 
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
  @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

  @return unquote($value)

$shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700)
$shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200)
$shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, after this, now I get an "Invaid CSS" error after `&:` saying that there was an expected pseudoclass and instead saw `after`, this happens at `#stars`.

Comment: @SheldonAndre Have you tried changing &: after to &:after? (no space)